# Bash script via php (apache2)

Tags: php, bash, apache2, sudoers

Bonsoir, I have a bash script that run normally on terminal but when I run it via php, it runs some commands(thoses that not have sudo).
This is my file sudoers where i give the rights to www-data :

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
www-data ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

And this error that i get when i type sudo service apache2 status :

```
juin 01 21:33:13 les-tatates-cm sudo[21697]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [www-data]
```

How to fix it ? Need help please !

Comment: try `NOPASSWD:   SERVICES`

Comment: Always the same error @UlyssesMarx!

Comment: What OS are you using ?

Comment: I'am using linux, Ubuntu 16.04.4

Comment: That happen when the user actually still has a password check the /etc/passwd

Comment: I do how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
$ssh->login('username', 'password');

$ssh->read('[prompt]');
$ssh->write("sudo command\n");
$ssh->read('Password:');
$ssh->write("Password\n");
echo $ssh->read('[prompt]');
?>
```